# Magento 2 : make a multiple step register form

Tags: magento2, frontend, forms, register

I want to make a multiple-step register form in Magento 2. How can I do it?
[image]

Any helps? Thank in advance.

Comment: reference for step js => http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Comment: any update on this i tried to look at the link @SavanPatel put but that didnt work